# Storing Hash128 as a readonly instance variable breaks hash calculation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code that looks like this:

```
public class HashWrapper {
  private readonly Hash128 hash;

  public HashWrapper() {
    this.hash = new Hash128();
  }

  public HashWrapper Append(String val) {
    this.hash.Append(val);
    return this;
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return this.hash.ToString();
  }
}
```

The following code produces a hash string with all 0s:

`new HashWrapper().Append("Hello").ToString();`

However, if I use Hash128 directly I get the correct value: `var hash = new Hash128(); hash.Append("Hello"); hash.ToString();`

Any ideas why this would happen? It seems like Hash128 doesn't like being heap allocated?

Comment: What is `Hash128`, exactly?

Comment: It's a type provided by Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Hash128.html The implementation is native

Comment: `Hash128` looks like a struct, Append should mutate the internal fields? Then I don't think it can be readonly. The C# compiler might be assuming that `hash == default` and therefore doesn't need to be stored anywhere. Do you have a good reason for allocating a new object on the heap?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman  `readonly` on a field only makes the field assignable in a constructor, you can still have a mutable object in a `readonly` field - but then again, it is a value-type which means it needs to reassign the field to save the mutated state, but I'd have thought you'd get a compile-time error or warning about that?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Of course, I think we can agree that Unity has made a huge design-mistake by using a struct for mutable data, ugh. I guess just don't use their own `Hash128` type and use your own?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman good catch. That was the issue. There was no compile-time warning about this. Maybe the compiler wasn't able to catch it because the implementation was native?

Comment: Unity design decisions are all about optimising for speed and reducing allocations. So creating a struct type for this makes some sense.

Comment: Is the issue related to *being stored in a field and used via HashWrapper* or *being stored in a **readonly** field and used via HashWrapper*? The claimed working code only shows direct access to Hash128, not wrapped access of a non-readonly field.

Comment: @user2864740 The issue is that Hash128 was stored in a **readonly** field. Changing `private readonly Hash128 hash;` to `private Hash128 hash;` fixed the issue.

Comment: @Max That's useful information. I would include in the main content as well.